# How to Unregister Push Notification?

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to unregister push notification for the app when the user gets logout. I'm using this code in logout action:

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```

then ho do i know the app is unregistered  and what is the apns response to the server and is there a need of internet for unregistering?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803793/ios-unregisterforremotenotifications-does-not-work-in-airplane-mode

Comment: Read the documentation. It seems to suggest that `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` should not be used like this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this on your server that is sending push notifications out.  When the user logs out, the server can be notified and suspend sending those APNS messages to Apple.  Apple doesn't like getting push notifications for a device that isn't supposed to be receiving them.

Comment: how do i send the push notifications out. and is there a need of internet for sending push notification out?

Comment: Push notifications require the Internet.  There are several open source libraries out there for APNS.  Google is your friend - http://www.google.com/#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=bcd9d7b95a7fab4f&q=apns+library

Answer (score 1):

There is alternative for this,

You can send some flag value to server (using webservice) when user logout, and server send notification to only logged user..

Comment: but for that we need internet if you take facebook app they were doing without internet also they are allowing user to be log out the

Comment: Push notifications require the Internet.